# Designing a weighted keyword matching string-compare to sort resume docs by relevance

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, csv, doc

I need to make some design docs- I'm at a loss to decide on data-type and process issues ...i know there are far more experienced designers who can help me find a **KISS-simple ADT** or template that i haven't been able to find **so lets start with requirements:**

1. **The main function retrieves resumes and ranks them from MOST to Least based on:**
2. ****User-defined keywords**** that are assigned an int Value

//the best type seems to be **pairing**:

```
template <class udKeyword, class IntValue>
class Pair{
  Public: udKeyword one; IntValue two;
}
```

//note ...a PairList class is also req'd

3. The **ranked_doc_list** needs to be **massively scalable** so I am unsure whether to call a sort when the user requests the **ranked_doc_list** or if **res_docs** should insert themselves (and push_back lower-ranked res_docs) as they come in. that approach seems best but also seems like a lot of waste in terms of computation and memory.

I'm starting with a very simple example. 
The client is going to enter **udKeywod/Value pairs** My_client_company will post 
"*Experienced Bartender needed - please email resume to client@xxxxx.yyy"*

**assume** "Experienced" = 7, "Bartend" = 5, "Bartending" = 5, "Customer Service" = 4, "Diploma" = 3... ...etc. (an enumeration)

I would prefer the resumes come in as .doc files that I can break down by ****resume_filename**** and build a template for each document as opposed to making it functional as well:

```
/*FORGIVE MY C++ STL (untested - I'm on a laptop running Win7 that 
  makes me miss my HP-UX and SParc-Solaris Labs greatly*/

//extract the  file name and parse/allocate the text into a CSV array

template <class filename, class CSV_unordered_list>
class doc_data_pull{ 
  public: 
    string name() = new resdoc.filename; 
    int wordQty = CSv_unordered_list.get_size();
    string csv[];
    void getCSVarray{ 
        for(int i=0; i < wordQty; CSV_unordered_list.next(); i++){
            csv[i] = CSV_unordered_list.get_string();
    }
}
```

//compare csv array using a **strcompare** wwith udKeywords and assign a score to name

```
template <class PairList; class doc_data_pull;>
class ranksResume{

    getCSV_matches_and scores(csv[]; name();{
    int PLsize = Pairlist.size();
    int i=0;
    int score[] = 0;
    int PLindex = 0;
    while (PLindex < Pairlist.size();{
        if (csv[i] == Pairlist.udKeyword()** //string-compare is the centerpiece of the logic
            score  = Pairlist.score //the user-defined keyword matched 
            i++; Pairlist.next();
            PLindex++;}
         else{i++; PLindex++;}}//end else and while
    //report the score and name() for QC sanshot
    cout<< name() /*should be initial filename uploaded to /root */ << scored a << score \n;
```

**//a listype for **ranksResume** is also skipped over due to laziness**

```
#include "udKeyword.h"  //for user to define keywords per job posting
#include "intKey.h"     //an integer value with a unique identifier to prevent "ties"
#include "pair.h"       //keyword, value from user
#include "pairlist.h"   //user-defined and created listype Keyword and Relevance metric
#include "filename.h"   //extracts the text "filename" or 1st txt line for txt-only resumes
#include "CSVunorderdList.h" //creates a CSV array for str-compare to udKeyword
#include "doc_data_pull.h"//provides CSV for each doc AND the resume-filename
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ranksResume.h" //WIP
using namespace std;

int main(){//I have almost no recollection of switches in the .cpp so bear w/ me
    char input;
    cout << "What would you like this bogus document-SEO-based idea of yours to do? <<endl;
    cin >> input;

    switch(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) {
    case a : Add a new Keywored
    case b : change the value of a Keyword
    case c : you have << filename.size() << new resumes. Display all? << ranksResumeList.print()' 
    Case d : display just the top 10. << ranksResumeList.printTopTen();
    case e : delete a resume
    case f : favorite a resume
    case g : mark this job search complete
    case h : exit.}

    return 0;
    //take benzodiazepenes
}//end main
```

Anyway that is probably my first pile of object code in a decade. It's partial, probably loaded with bugs and type-missmatch ... but you can prob see where my pseudocode-solution are headed I did search for this a week ago an found very little posts or comments of worth on paired data lists that define the rank of documents (or strings, objects....) based on a robotic selection of keywords and subjective weight to develop "relevance" it's bs but customers really want to sort client documents this way...it's institutionalized SEO corruption but whatever...I'll work on anything for a few bucks.As designers though....I really want to know which algorithms and ADTs you would use to solve this.DONT feel obligated to give answers in C/C++/Java...plus I never touched on how a (php?) function I'd would implement the receipt and likely sorting/indexing of .doc files.

Comment: First of all, you might want to explain whether you're doing this as an assignment/learning exercise (i.e. one user/PC, can scan .docs at startup, STL containers, no need for persistence/IPC) or for some actual company with distributed users (where a backing DB is desirable, persistence is needed, new .docs should be scanned and incrementally added to the DB, new keywords should trigger background re-scans etc., server jobs are needed etc.).  Do you have a .doc-reading library?  Enough experience for this? - honestly....

Comment: This is a small government contract job I'm working on...I'm part of this program that is supposed to help people with disabilities find jobs...they hired this new kid and he is obsessed with and SEO-resume to meet each job posting, especially online where it is not uncommon for companies to receive 1000 to 10000 res_docs. He wanted to know if technology existed to sort docs by relevance to weighted keywords and I said "yeah webdevs are SICK with it"creating text to optimize job-search aggregate hosts. It would be interesting to see if res-hacking actually works.

Comment: I intend to try this out... but what good is it if I don't break-down the mechanics of how an enterprise document storage/sort/retrieve program really works OR if this has become an SOP for large companies with ZERO or 1 HR professional.

Comment: Sounds like an awful lot of work just to prove to yourself that the keyword-weighted search approach is plausible - of course it is, and of course recruitment firms use such tools, albeit with increasing smarts to adjust weights by overall resume length and keyword use, recognise negations ala "didn't use" etc., find quoted phrases etc..  You'd get a better idea checking out features on some leading intranet search freeware - it's likely some smaller recruiters repurpose such software for such use, and some commercial resume database software does the same internally.

Comment: I appreciate the info...I'm not going to actually try to build the back end in in C++ and implement the front-end on an enterprise level server. I just want to know what Abstract Data Types to use and whether you would update the list in real time or call a sort whenever the user selects "Display" and queue new res_docs in-between user requests. If you consider that at ANY company the hiring mgr. probably would request "Display" once or twice each day...I know topics get locked that attract opinion this is algorithm analysis what is FASTEST and CHEAPEST (in terms of flops and memory usage?)

Comment: At simplest, there should be 1) an associate container (likely hash table, a binary tree would do) of keywords to weightings, synonyms etc.., a `map<Weight, vector<Resume*>>` or similar associating keyword-specific weight (an `int`?) with a list of resume references.  Then given a set of keywords you can start working through the highest weights of each seeking good overall scores... work downwards through the weights until you've found enough results.  New docs `push_back` to the corresponding `vector<Resume*>` (a list has better worst-case insertion, but much worse iteration due to caching).

Comment: Re "at ANY company the hiring mgr. probably would request "Display" once or twice each day" - that's likely at a potential employer polling for new applicants to their smallish job pool, but a recruitment firm may well have agents searching several times a minute, and on varied criterion.

Comment: Have not considered user scalability. n/a in this case. your prev answer is sufficeint. thx!

Comment: You're welcome... good luck with it.